# How to correctly express “I don't like it too”?

Tags: grammaticality

What are correct ways to express that one also feels the same way with statement such as, “I don't like it.” or “I can't do it.”? E.g., do all of these have the correct form and same meaning?

1. I don't like it too.
2. I don't like it also.
3. I don't like it either.
4. I don't like it neither.
5. I also don't like it.
6. I too don't like it.

Are there any other ways to express this meaning, which don't change the form too much?

Comment: As others have said, #4 is off.  But one could say, "_Neither do I._"

Comment: @J.R. I wonder whether people who use double negatives might actually say #4? I could easily see somebody who could say  “Me and Huck ain’t never done nothin’ like that, Aunt Polly!” generating #4 as well.

Comment: @tchrist: Prolly so. But, insofar as "correctness" goes, I'd have to caveat it somehow; it's "informal" at best.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"I don't like it either" is the most common way a native English speaker would express this sentiment.

"I don't like it too" and "I don't like it also" are generally seen as improper because, arranged this way, there's a contradiction between the negative "don't" and the inclusive "too"/"also"; the statement seems to reject and affirm at the same time. Contrary to that, "I also don't like it" and "I too don't like it", by placing the inclusive word closer to the subject, implies that the speaker is including themselves in a group that is rejecting the object ("it"). These uses are seen as archaic, but the sentences may be used in an artistic way to call attention to the statement.

"I don't like it neither" is improper because of the double negative, but if you were making fun of a stereotypical "unsophisticated" culture or dialect such as a "redneck", you might use it.

Comment: A good reference is Georgia Green's 1968 "On 'too' and 'either', and not just on 'too' and 'either', either" in _CLS 4_. Negative polarity is involved.

Answer (score 2):

You have asked how to correctly express *I don't like it too* and as other answers have stated, your example number 3 is the preferred choice. However, the colloquial response most often used to ***I don't like it*** is ***me neither***.

Comment: Or *me either*, or *Nor I* or... The thing about colloquialisms is that they tend to be localized.

Answer (score 0):

Except for `I don't like it neither`, I think all options are correct. The aforementioned form has a double negation and hence it can be confusing, to say the least.

Other options such as `I also don't like it` seem quite alright. They also convey the intended meaning without any ambiguity.

Comment: Sorry, but 1 and 2 are definitely to be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use "too", you could say "I dislike it too", though that's less colloquial.